# How to count current and previous dates?

Tags: mysql

For example MySQL `NOW()` returns `2013-01-09 12:20:06`, so i need to count all rows as specified below.

**Current:**

- Hour: from 2013-01-09 12:00:00 till `NOW()`
- Day: from 2013-01-08 00:00:00 till `NOW()`
- Month: from 2013-01-01 00:00:00 till `NOW()`

**Previous**

- Hour: 2013-01-09 11:00:00 - 2013-01-09 12:00:00
- Day: 2013-01-08 00:00:00 - 2013-01-08 23:59:59
- Month: 2012-12-01 00:00:00 - 2013-01-01 00:00:00

I tried something like:

```
WHERE
    `date` >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00')
AND `date` >= DATE_SUB(
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00'),
    INTERVAL 10 MONTH
)
```

But may be there is more convenient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**For CURRENT:**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00');
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00');
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00');
```

**For PREVIOUS:**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'), DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'), DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00'), DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Check this link [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2c333/1)